# How do I use pointers correctly in my code?

Tags: c

Hello everyone I just started learning how to use pointers and I got stuck in my code. I need to write a code that modifies(corrects the uppercases and lowercases and finds out the year of every citizen) and sorts a list of citizens. For an example if the user entry is:

4 //just the number of citizens

lAna lanIc 1999

lana lanac 1999

laNa LaneC 1989

lAna lanOc 1999

the display must be :

18; Lanac, Lana

18; Lanic, Lana

18; Lanoc, Lana

28; Lanec, Lana

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

typedef struct {
char name[26];
char surname[26];
int birth;
}   citizen;   //the structer for the citizen

void modify(citizen *g);
int compare(citizen g1, citizen g2); //compares citizens by birth or          surname or name 
void sort(citizen g[], int);  //insertion sort

int main()
{   
    int n, i;
    citizen g[100];

    scanf("%d", &n);

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
       scanf("%s %s %d", g[i].name, g[i].surname, &g[i].birth);
       modify(g + i);
    }

    sort(g, n);

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
         printf("%2d; %s %s\n", g[i].birth, g[i].surname, g[i].name);
    }

    return 0;
}

void modify(citizen *g) { //here I'm having trouble
    int i = 0; 

    //trying to correct the name
    if(isalpha(*g[i].name[0])) {   
       *g[i].name[0] = toupper(*g[i].name[0]);
     }
    for(i = 1; i < strlen(*g[i].name); i++) {
       *g[i].name = toupper(*g[i].name);
     }
    //then the surname

    if(isalpha(*g[i].surname[0])) {
        *g[i].surnma[0] = toupper(*g[i].surname[0]);
     }
     for(i = 1; i < strlen(*g[i].surname); i++) {
        *g[i].surname = toupper(*g[i].surname);

     }
     *g[i].birth = 2017 - *g[i].birth; //finding how old is the citizen

 }


int compare(citizen g1, citizen g2) {
    if(g1.birth == g2.birth) {
        if(!strcmp(g1.surname, g2.surname)) {
               return strcmp(g1.name,g2.name);
        }
        else {
              return strcmp(g1.surname, g2.surname);
        }
     }
    else if (g1.birth > g2.birth) {
              return 1;
    }
              return -1;
}



void sort(citizen g[], int n) { //insertion sort
   int i, j;
   citizen tmp;

   for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
       tmp = g[i];
       j = i;
       while(j > 0 && compare(g[j-1], tmp)) {
            g[j] = g[j - 1];
            j--;
        }
        g[j] = tmp;

     }
 }
```

Comment: What now, C or C#?

Comment: @tilz0R oh sorry C

Comment: Is this C or C#? Because it really doesn't look like C# to me. You can also do everyone a flavour and indent your code properly.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @UnholySheep how do I proprely use pointers in function modify ?

Comment: `*g[i].name[0]` what woukd that mean? Why are you sticking `*` in front of an expression?

Comment: *Why* are you trying to use pointers?

Comment: @n.m . cuz we're learning to use pointers now aande we have to solve it using pointers

Comment: A good approach to learning pointers would be to start with a function that modifies *a single string*.  Try this: `void fixCase(char* str)`. Also try to avoid unneeded copies, this can also teach you to use pointers. For example, calling your comoare function makes unnecessary copies of large structures and you want to avoid that.

Comment: So, concerning your `modify()`, you hopefully learnt: `*g[i].name[0]` is wrong (thanks @n.m.). `g[i].name[0]` (with `int i = 0;` before) will do as well as `g[0].name[0]` or `(*(g + 0)).name[0]` or `(*g).name[0]` or `g->name[0]`. This is now your little C Pointer Primer...

Comment: @Scheff is my wrong because the priority of . is higer than * ?

Comment: One issue is the operator precedence. The more important fact is: `g` is of type `citizen*` (i.e. a pointer to `citizen`) but `g[0]` returns type `citizen` (now, it's not a pointer anymore). Btw. the result of subscript (i.e. `[]` - the array/pointer access with brackets) is actually an LValue. Thus, it may be used on left hand side of assingment also. (I would call this "reference" but in C, the term "LValue" is preferred.) Of course, you may it not use as LValue if it would be prefixed with `const`.

Answer (score 1):

The basics:

In your main function this:

```
citizen g[100];
```

declares an array of 100 citizens. `g` is an array which is not a pointer.

In your modify function

```
modify(citizen *g)
```

`g` is a pointer to a citizen. It is not an array. So you're probably asking why it is legal to do this:

```
modify(g + i);
```

The reason is that, in the context of using `g` in an expression, it is transformed by the compiler into a pointer to its first element. We say "`g` *decays* to a pointer to its first element".

There are two ways to access the thing(s) that a pointer points to (we say "*dereference* the pointer"). The first is to use the `*` operator. If `p` is `int*` we can do

```
int x = *p;
```

If `p` points to an `int` that is in an array of `int`s, we can do pointer arithmetic. So we could do

```
int y = *(p + 3);
int z = *(p - 2);
```

If `p` points to the third element of an array that is at least size 6, `y` now has the same value as the sixth element and `z` has the same value as the first element.

The second way to dereference a pointer is to use subscript syntax. The syntax `p[i]` is exactly equivalent to `*(p + i)` and I mean *exactly*. Addition is commutative so `p + i == i + p` which means `*(p + i) == *(i + p)` which means (and this is legal in C) `p[i] == i[p]` Anyway each of the statements above can be written using subscripts

```
int x = p[0];
int y = p[3];
int z = p[-2];
```

Except to save our sanity, we tend to only use subscript syntax if p is a pointer to the first element of an array or the first element of a malloc'd block.

If `p` is a pointer to a `struct` (like your `citizen` struct, you can access the fields in the struct by dereferencing `p` and using the normal diot syntax.

```
int myBirth = (*p).birth;
```

The parentheses are necessary because the dot operator normally has higher precedence than the * operator. With `*p.birth` the C compiler thinks that `p` s a struct with a field called `birth` which it tries to dereference as a pointer. C provides a shortcut syntax for the `(*p).birth` thing which  is

```
int myBirth = p->birth; // Exactly equivalent to (*).birth
```

Finally in C, you can obtain a pointer to an arbitrary object with the & operator.

```
int x = 0;
int* p = &x; // p is a pointer to x.
```

So when we say `g` decays to a pointer to its first element, what we mean is that the compiler transforms

```
modify(g + i);
```

to 
    modify(&g[0] + i);

So, you see, your modify function receives a pointer to an element of `g`. Looking at the first couple of lines of the function:

```
if(isalpha(*g[i].name[0])) {   
   *g[i].name[0] = toupper(*g[i].name[0]);
 }

Because i is 0 at this point, `g[i].name` is the same as `(*g).name` or `g->name`. Use the last one for clarity. The `name` field is an array of chars, so `name[0]` is the first character of the name, which is what you want. You have an extra dereference with the leading * that you don't need. The above should be

if (isalpha(g->name[0])) {   
   g->name[0] = toupper(g->name[0]);
 }
```

Except `toupper` does the `isalpha` check for you, so all that becomes

```
 g->name[0] = toupper(g->name[0]);
```

I'll leave it to you to fix the rest of the function, except to mention the rather bad bug here:

```
 for(i = 1; i < strlen(*g[i].surname); i++) {
    *g[i].surname = toupper(*g[i].surname);

 }
```

This actually makes no sense to me at all.

Comment: Thank you so much for this great explanation. I understand pointers now way better

Answer (score 0):

Instead of dereference pointer your way, I will give you answer here:

```
void modify(citizen *g) { //here I'm having trouble
    int i = 0; 

    //trying to correct the name
    //Is this really necessary?
    if (isalpha(g->name[0])) {   
        g->name[0] = toupper(g->name[0]);
    }
    for (i = 1; i < strlen(g->name); i++) {
        g->name[i] = toupper(g->name[i]);
    }

    //then the surname
    //Is this really necessary?
    if (isalpha(g->surname[0])) {
        g->surname[0] = toupper(g->surname[0]);
    }
    for (i = 1; i < strlen(g->surname); i++) {
        g->surname[i] = toupper(g->surname[i]);
    }
    g->birth = 2017 - g->birth; //finding how old is the citizen
}
```

I've also modify you `compare` function:

```
int compare(citizen *g1, citizen *g2) {
    if (g1->birth == g2->birth) {
        int resp = strcmp(g1->surname, g2->surname);
        if (!resp) {
           return strcmp(g1->name, g2->name);
        }
        return resp;
    } else if (g1->birth > g2->birth) {
        return 1;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Now, you took him all the joy to find out how to program properly in C with pointers by reading a good manual... At least, you gave him the task to find out by himself how to format the non-first chars to lower case.

Comment: The way how he started (and he didn't even try to compile because of mistakes) he can have that `joy` for 10 years and he won't figure out. Btw..does it mean my answer is wrong?

Comment: The duplicated `strcmp(g1->surname, g2->surname)` could be prevented by using a local variable. In `modify()`, you used `toupper()` for the non-first characters also. The original assignment was lower case...

Comment: I don't care about how and what code works. I just care about pointers usage!

Comment: @tilz0R enclosing text in asterix shows it *like this*. The code formatting really troubles me.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya looks like you are following me for some reason. May I know what is the problem here? What is wrong with code formatting?

Comment: IMHO the `isalpha(g->name[0])` is unnecessary because `toupper()` should affect lower case letters only.

Comment: I do believe you that but as I said, I don't care about that. Just what pointers do.

Comment: @tilz0R actually only the first letter has to be toupper(); "Lana" but nevermind the pointers are working correctly, thank you

Comment: @tilz0R I am not following you. I am looking at new questions. There is no problem with you code formatting. In your comment, you wrote joy as `joy`. We use that formatting for code here on SO. I am just saying if you want to stress some word you can use *this* or __this__. It is just a suggestion unrelated to the question.